# cant send table to HTML via flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, cisco

I am trying to get the last input time of the switch interfaces and post it to html via flask but even though I managed to get the list, I couldnt push it to html.

what is my mistake here?

```
    def index():
        logging.basicConfig(filename='netmiko.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
        device = {
        'device_type':'cisco_ios_telnet',
        'ip': '10.10.20.250',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'cisco',
        'port':23,
        }

        with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
        # Enter enable mode
            net_connect.enable()

        # Send "show interfaces" command and get output
            show_output = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces')

        net_connect.disconnect()

        interfaces_list = []
        for line in show_output.splitlines():
            if line.startswith('Gigabit'):
            # extract the interface name
                interface_name = line.split()[0]
            # extract the last input time
                if line.startswith('  Last input '):
                last_input_time = line.split('  Last input ')[1].split(',')[0]
            interfaces_list.append(f"{interface_name} - Last input {last_input_time}")
            else:
                continue    
            
        return render_template('index.html', interfaces=interfaces_list)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is my html code (saved as index.html under templates)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Show Interfaces</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Interface</th>
                    <th>Last Input</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for interface in interfaces %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ interface.interface }}</td>
                    <td>{{ interface.last_input }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

for those who doesnt know what is the output of show interfaces, I will give you this example

```
     GigabitEthernet3/0 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
     Hardware is iGbE, address is 0c82.6bf0.000c (bia 0c82.6bf0.000c)
     Description: VPC
     MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
        reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
     Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
     Keepalive set (10 sec)
     Auto Duplex, Auto Speed, link type is auto, media type is RJ45
     output flow-control is unsupported, input flow-control is unsupported
     ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
     Last input 00:21:33, output 00:00:01, output hang never
     Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
     Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
     Queueing strategy: fifo
     Output queue: 0/0 (size/max)
     5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
        7 packets input, 1816 bytes, 0 no buffer
        Received 6 broadcasts (6 multicasts)
        0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
        0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
        0 watchdog, 6 multicast, 0 pause input
        749 packets output, 60803 bytes, 0 underruns
        0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
        0 unknown protocol drops
        0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
        0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
        0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     GigabitEthernet3/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
     Hardware is iGbE, address is 0c82.6bf0.000d (bia 0c82.6bf0.000d)
     Description: VPC
     MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Please ensure your python code is indented properly.

Comment: my code is working fine if I use print instead of using flask.
the problem is integration with Html.